# Inverse distribution function and random walk

Tags: probability-distributions, random-walk, cumulative-distribution-functions

Suppose $P$ denotes the probability distribution function of a random walk $\sum^n X_i$ and is given already.
Can anybody please intuitively and mathematically explain, how [the inverse distribution function](https://www.statisticshowto.com/inverse-distribution-function/#:%7E:text=The%20inverse%20distribution%20function%20for,less%20than%20a%20certain%20x.) can be used to generate random walk using the given $P$?

Comment: It is a rather hard problem to calculate the probability distribution function if you are given the random walk.  So the reverse problem?  No way!

There are some special cases, like if the distribution is normal or Cauchy.

On the problem of calculating the probability distribution function, there are some approximation formulas out there.  See http://faculty.missouri.edu/~stephen/preprints/disttail.html.

Comment: Thanks for introducing the paper. Actually i have difficulty to understand(intuitively and mathematically) the relation between cumulative distribution function(and its inverse) with the random walk, assuming that the probability distribution function is given.